# <untitled> download unsuccessful

Tags: android, download, android-browser

I have a mobile application connected to a web app that let customer download .DAT file after purchase confirmation. The customer is seeing the "Download File" button when clicking it start downloads after 3 secs it gives <untitled> download unsuccessful

```
<a href="'.$url.'/used/'.$productcode.'" title="order" download>Download File</a>
```

I've created a static HTML file and open it via Android Browser as a troubleshoot I got the same result

```
<a href="/file.dat" title="file" download>Download File</a>
```

<Untitled> Download Unsuccessful

I have added Addtype to .htaccess

```
Addtype application/octet-stream .dat
```

Also didn't fix the issue.

Comment: did you got the solution?